# Почему стоит запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему стоит запятая после слова "мыслей": Учитель, образ его мыслей, — вот что самое главное во всяком воспитании и обучении?

Comment: Ошибочно стоит.

Answer (score 3):

> *Учитель, образ его мыслей, — вот что самое главное во всяком воспитании и обучении.*
>
> Почему стоит запятая после слова "мыслей"?

Если не поставить эту запятую, то слово "учитель" может восприниматься как обращение.

Comment: Страшно интересно, о каком же третьем лице речь? Чей образ мысли главнее?

Answer (score 2):

Запятая в вашем примере не нужна. Вот правило.
Если обобщающее слово следует за однородными членами предложения, то перед ним ставится тире:
*Обман, расчёт, холодное ревнивое тиранство и ужас над бедным разорванным сердцем — **вот что** понял он в этом бесстыдно не таившемся более смехе* (Дост.).

[**Обобщающие слова при однородных членах предложения (п. 6)**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103)

Обратите также внимание, что это это предложение есть в интернете — без **запятой!**

Comment: *Обратите также внимание* - в Интернете есть всё. Что это за аргумент? Ну и то, что члены здесь не обязательно однородные, тоже понятно..

Comment: Действительно, в Интернете есть вариант без запятой  и источник указан, но это будто бы не аргумент.  А вот откуда к нам пришел вариант с запятой - неизвестно, но именно он взят за образец, который нужно объяснить.

Comment: Sibylla, запятая могла быть поставлена по ошибке.

Answer (score 1):

Мне тоже хочется поставить эту запятую. Если не по правилам, то хотя бы как "авторскую".

Смысл такой, что "образ его мыслей" воспринимается как уточнение к "учителю". Без запятой это не так. Это первое.

Второе. Без запятой не очевидно, что "вот что..." относится к Учителю, а не только к "образу".

Слабую мотивацию для объяснения этой запятой вижу в следующем. Напишем конструкцию со скобками: *Учитель (образ его мыслей) - вот что самое главное...*. Теперь заменим скобки на запятые. Получим исходный вариант.

Можно и с другого конца. *Учитель, образ его мыслей, воспринимается как самое главное...* А теперь заменим вторую часть исходной конструкцией. Придем к тому же, запятая остаётся на своём месте.

Всё это говорит о том, что у запятой есть некоторый мотив помимо того, по которому ставится тире. Другими словами запятая и тире здесь не единый знак.

Повторяю, это не рекомендация ставить запятую, это лиши объяснение авторской позиции.

(+)
Если кто не понял, при такой трактовке члены предложения не однородные. Поэтому и правило, приводимое в некоторых ответах не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна запятая, подлежащее выражено однородным рядом: **Учитель, образ его мыслей — вот что самое главное во всяком воспитании и обучении.**

В том же предложении нет запятой: [Пословицы, поговорки, которые свидетельствуют о предназначении учителя и педагогической деятельности | Ответы Mail.Ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/94846188)

**Примеры:**

Не называние греха....а ощущение самой материи греха, самой его стихии, боль и скорбь о нем, жажда освобождения от него ― **вот что** важно. [А. В. Ельчанинов. Записи (1926-1934)]

И без строгости-с, без карательных мер ― **вот что** важно!.. [Н. Н. Златовратский. Золотые сердца (1877)]

**Дополнение (однородные или неоднородные члены)**

1) **Однородные члены**: Учитель и образ его мыслей ―  вот что самое главное. Имеется в виду: сам учитель как личность и образ его мыслей.

2) **Пояснение**: Учитель, то есть образ его мыслей, ―  вот что самое главное. Звучит как-то не очень: **от учителя остается только образ мыслей.**

3) **Присоединение:** Учитель, в частности образ его мыслей, ―  вот что самое главное. Это уже ближе к теме, но тоже выглядит как-то не очень корректно: **частное и главное перемешаны в одном суждении.**

Заметим также, что **при пояснении** (при отсутствии союзов) возможно обособление запятой, а вот **для бессоюзного присоединения** одних запятых мало. **В результате семантика становится неясной и превращается в так называемую авторскую позицию.**

Поэтому предлагается остановиться на однородных членах и запятую не ставить, особенно авторскую.

Итак,  пока 3:2 в пользу однородных членов при одной неопределенной позиции. Интересно было бы услышать еще чье-либо мнение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно критически относиться к этой фразе в целом как излишне категоричной, но формально ***образ его мыслей*** в ней — уточнение, которое, как известно, требует обособления. Без замыкающей запятой эта фраза тоже может существовать, если  ***учителя и образ его мысли*** представлять единым и суммой ценного, что даёт право автору считать это главным.

Answer (score 0):

Вторая запятая тут лишняя, и обобщающее слово здесь не причем - тут "учитель" и "образ его мысли" - однородные подлежащие, а "вот что самое главное в жизни" - сказуемое.  Да, да, вы не ослышались - сказуемое может быть выражено целым предложением.

Comment: Вы ослышались: не в жизни, и это прекрасно.

Comment: Очень путано излагаете, хоть и с претензией на некую сенсационность. . На фоне орфографической ошибки  в "ни при чем" это выглядит несколько странно. Источник вашего утверждения про сказуемое, выраженное предложением, не назовете?

Comment: Да, еще забыл спросить, а тире-то тогда зачем между подлежащим и сказуемым?

Answer (score 0):

Я не вижу других причин помимо авторского понимания *образа мыслей* как уточняющего элемента к *учителю*.

Идея о том, что *учитель* в ином случае может восприниматься как обращение, выглядит надуманной.

Answer (score 0):

Опираясь на ответ, данный @Sibylla , хочу заметить, что как не расставляй знаки препинания, здесь частное и главное перемешаны в одном суждении. Образ мыслей не существует в отрыве от учителя, поэтому вариант с **однородными членами** кажется мне нелогичным. Варинат с **пояснением** тоже не логичен (как пишет @Sibylla, от учителя остается только образ мыслей). Логичнее видеть здесь **присоединение**: Учитель, в частности образ его мыслей, ― вот что самое главное. Значит, запятая нужна:

**Учитель, образ его мыслей, — вот что самое главное во всяком воспитании и обучении.**